# Using the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition to calculate limits

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit of a function to show that

$\lim \sin(x^2 + y^2) = 0$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

Okay, first observe that:

$\|(x,y) - (0,0)\| < \delta$ $\implies$ $\sqrt{ x^2 + y^2} < \delta$ $\implies$ $\sin(x^2 + y^2) < \sin(\delta^2)$ $\implies$ $|\sin(x^2 + y^2)| < \epsilon$ if we choose $\epsilon := \sin(\delta^2)$. However, $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$. This contradicts $\epsilon > 0.$ But notice that $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ for small $\theta$. Since $\epsilon, \delta$ are chosen to be arbitrarily small, then $\epsilon := \sin(\delta^2) \approx \delta^2 > 0$. For this choice of $\epsilon$, the limit of $f$ tends to $0$. Q.E.D.

I am wondering if this works. I appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to show that for any given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists and $\delta < 0$ such that $\| (x,y \| < \delta$ implies $| sin(x^2+y^2) | < \epsilon$. That's not what you've done.

Comment: You need to find $\delta$ given an $\epsilon>0$. So given $\epsilon>0$ can you find a $\delta$ so that $0<\sin(\delta^2)<\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, $\delta$ is precisely $\sqrt(\epsilon)$ GIVEN that $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$

Comment: You don't need $\sin\theta \approx \theta$, only that $|\sin(\theta)|\leq|\theta|$ for all theta. (It is only true that $\sin(\theta)\approx \theta$ for a narrow range of theta. If $\epsilon=100$, for example...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't choose $\varepsilon$ given $\delta$, but the other way around! However, the method is not completely wrong. Given $\varepsilon>0$ you need to find $\delta$ such that, if $0<\|(x,y)\|<\delta$, then $\sin(x^2+y^2)<\varepsilon$.

Now, *suppose* you have found this $\delta$; then $0<\|(x,y)\|<\delta$ is the same as $0<x^2+y^2<\delta^2$. Now, recall that, for $\theta>0$, $\sin\theta<\theta$. So, we also have $\sin(x^2+y^2)<\sin(\delta^2)<\delta^2$ (if we also assume $x^2+y^2<\pi/2$).

OK, we've found it! Get a fresh sheet and write the formal proof.

---

Given $\varepsilon>0$, set
$$
\delta=\sqrt{\min(\varepsilon,\pi/2)}
$$
For $0<\|(x,y)\|<\delta$, we have
$$
\sin(x^2+y^2)<\sin(\delta^2)<\delta^2\le\varepsilon
$$

- The first inequality holds because the sine is increasing in $(0,\pi/2)$;
- the second inequality follows from $\sin\theta<\theta$ for $\theta>0$;
- the third inequality follows from the choice of $\delta$.

---

#### Alternative proof.

Since $\sin\theta<\theta$, for $\theta>0$, we have, for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$,
$$
0\le \sin(x^2+y^2)<x^2+y^2
$$
and, by the squeeze theorem,
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sin(x^2+y^2)=0
$$
because
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+y^2)=0
$$
(an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of this statement is easier).